# Show FireFox cookies with Java

Tags: java, sqlite, firefox, cookies

I am writing a java applet that shows FireFox5 cookies. I need to open the cookies.sqlite file and read that database in Java.

I tried with org.sqlite.JDBC driver and got exception: file is encrypted or is not a database.
 Do I really need to decrypt the file first or get a permission?
 I tried SqlJetDb and it gives exception org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.SqlJetException: NOTADB: error code is NOTADB

Is there anything else do the task of showing FireFox5 cookies?
 Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want any third party application be able to read your cookies (like you authentication tokens)?

Comment: Does it have to be a Java applet? A standard Firefox addon might be much easier to write, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: In addition to the sandbox for applets, even being able to read from the local file system, you would still need to find the firefox profile. On most systems, it exists inside the users profile (%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles on Windows, and somewhere in the home directory in linux), with the actual profile directory having a randomized name.

Comment: Just in case anybody will need it I have downloaded the latest sqlite jdbc 3.7.2 and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a signed applet? By default Java applets run in a sandbox for security and cannot access the filesystem: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Answer (score 0):

Python has a builtin sqlite database. You can manipulate the cookies.sqlite through Python, copy the data to a text file and then use a Java application, but through Java applet, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Please take the time, and reread your postings for spelling errors and so on. Use a spellchecker for your browser, if available. Use the preview. See, how people with high rep. write their answers. Thanks.